# Flotcharts: How to place the legend on the right of the chart

Tags: jquery, css, charts, flot

So I have this chart that I generated with flotcharts library:

[image]

And the HTML is:

```
<div class="demo-container">
    <div id="legend-container"></div>
    <div id="placeholder" class="demo-placeholder"></div>
</div>
```

Now, I want to put the legend outside of the chart. So I start using this in my plot options:

```
var options = {
    ...,
    legend:{         
        container:$("#legend-container"),
    }
    ...
}
```

And the CSS:

```
#legend-container {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    border: 1px solid #E6E6E6;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

The result is:

[image]

That's great! But now I want to place the legend, not on top of (or on the bottom of) the chart, but on the right, on that blank & white space that there is next to the chart.

How to do it?

For completeness, the rest of my CSS is:

```
.demo-container {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 750px;
    height: 300px;
    padding: 20px 15px 15px 15px;
    margin: 15px auto 30px auto;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    background: #fff;
    background: linear-gradient(#f6f6f6 0, #fff 50px);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#f6f6f6 0, #fff 50px);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#f6f6f6 0, #fff 50px);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#f6f6f6 0, #fff 50px);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f6f6f6 0, #fff 50px);
    box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    -o-box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.demo-placeholder {
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.2em;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Switch the order of your divs and then float them left:

```
<div class="demo-container">        
    <div id="placeholder" class="demo-placeholder"></div>
    <div id="legend-container"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.demo-placeholder {
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    float: left; /*<-- ADD THIS*/
}
```

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xxurgxgv/).

Comment: mmm, interesting, the example works, but if I do the modifications in my code, the legend doesn't appear :-m

Comment: @knocte, can you post a link to your page?

Comment: actually, I'm not sure why it wasn't working before..., it works now, upvoting